# <script> tags working on Desktop browser but not on Mobile (MEAN app)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mobile

My app works perfectly normal on desktop browsers, however, when I open it in a mobile browser (Chrome/Safari/Firefox), the  tags for my angular app are not read. This is seen when my angular appears as {{user.first}}, for example, in the page, and the angular partials are not loaded at all. I would like the partials to be seen. This is my app's head:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- angular components -->
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela|Oswald:700|Neuton:700|Amatic+SC:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/scripts/config.js'></script>

<!-- date time picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<script src="/bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/moment/locale/pt.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <!-- controllers -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/controllers/reservation_controller.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/controllers/api_controller.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/controllers/user_controller.js'></script>
    <!-- factories -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/factories/reservation_factory.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/factories/venue_factory.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/factories/user_factory.js'></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-directive.js"></script>
    <link href="/assets/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
```

Comment: What does the error-log say?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* If the error is *This is seen when my angular appears as {{user.first}}* then the code provided must reproduce that.

Comment: @JohannesReuter my error-log doesnt indicate any anomaly on the backend. And I am still trying to figure out how to see the console of a mobile browser to check any frontend errors, though, so I am fumbling in the dark for that matter.

Comment: @BSMP sorry, its my first time posting a question over here, but thanks for the tips! The desired behavior is for my angular partials to show on the page the page of a mobile browser just as they currently do on desktop browsers. They are not showing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing obviously out of place, but your mobile browser's console can probably tell you a lot more about your problem than I can.

I highly recommend [Chrome's remote debugging tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NicholasAnderson suggestion, I was able to open up a console to check the problem. Oddly enough, a bug in an angular controller stopped all javascript from loading on a mobile browser, but a desktop browser apparently is more lenient and loaded all javascript  despite the error. Thus, it didn't work on the former but yes on the latter. Thanks for the suggestions! Another useful link for debugging on a mobile browser, if anyone is interested, is: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/